# Containers created by docker-compose do not appear in docker ps after their termination

Tags: docker, docker-compose

## My problem

When a docker container started with `docker run` exits, it is still listed in `docker ps -a` and its logs can be viewed with `docker logs <id>`.

However, when a docker container is started using `docker-compose`, it only appears in `docker ps` and `docker logs` while it runs. After it exists, its logs are inaccessible.

Needless to say, I did not delete the container, neither I used `--rm` or any other deletion parameter.

## Example

### While the container is running:

```
$ sudo docker logs d6a06d6655b1

>  test /usr/src/what/ever/src
> ava "--match=gong*" "--verbose" "--serial"


  ✔ gong › gong_tests › gong1
...
```

### After the container exits

```
$ sudo docker logs d6a06d6655b1
Error response from daemon: No such container: d6a06d6655b1
```

## My question

How can I see the logs of exited docker containers started by `docker-compose`?

## Update

It was a foolish mistake on my part, but in the rare case it might be relevant for others in the future:

My `Makefile` contained a `docker-compose down` command, which `rm`-ed the instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you have described.  If I started with a simple `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  example:
    image: alpine
    command: "echo this is a test"
```

And then run that with `docker-compose up`:

```
Starting compose_example_1 ... 
Starting compose_example_1 ... done
Attaching to compose_example_1
example_1  | this is a test
compose_example_1 exited with code 0
```

The container is visible as expected in the output of `docker ps -a`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
929fa9ccc631        alpine                        "echo this is a te..."   About a minute ago   Exited (0) 32 seconds ago                       compose_example_1
```

And `docker logs` works without a problem:

```
$ docker logs compose_example_1
this is a test
```

If you are seeing different behavior, please update your question to include the versions of `docker` and `docker-compose` that you are working with and a specific sequence of steps that reproduce the behavior.

Comment: *Thanks*. The `docker-compose` file version param is `version: "3.2"`. `docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21`, `Docker version 17.07.0-ce, build 8784753`. Will try to figure out what's the difference.

Comment: Hi, you're totally right. My bad. The `Makefile` contained a `docker-compose down` command, which `rm`-ed the instances. Thanks!